# How to configure Eclipse to use Aptana Studio 3's JavaScript Formatter instead of built-in formatter

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana3, formatter

It seems that Aptana Studio 3 plug-in is correctly installed; however, it also seems that the formatter is either failing or the built-in Eclipse formatter is taking precedence.  How can I insure that only the Aptana Studio 3 JavaScript formatter is being applied to code and not some other plug-in or the built-in formatter?

Comment: I also want to know an answer to this, for eclipse juno, using the javascript perspective.